# Logitech Script Binding

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I just made a script which has some mouse movement and presskey action. I am trying to bind F6 button instead of mouse button 5. How can I bind F6 button in this script? Namely, it is going to be like "if "F6" pressed then ...

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)

if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then

MoveMouseTo(60000, 11000)

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)

Sleep(20)

PressAndReleaseKey("y")

end
end
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried if event == "KeyPress" and arg == "f6", if event Keypress("f6) then but none of them worked.

Comment: It's impossible unless you have a Logitech keyboard where F6 is a G-button (for example, G513)